# weak_ptr's weird copy constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

the following are 2 of weak_ptr's constructors:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982126.aspx

```
weak_ptr(const weak_ptr&);

template<class Other>
weak_ptr(const weak_ptr<Other>&);
```

actual code (from `memory`):

```
weak_ptr(const weak_ptr& _Other)
{   // construct weak_ptr object for resource pointed to by _Other
    this->_Resetw(_Other);
}

template<class _Ty2>
weak_ptr(const weak_ptr<_Ty2>& _Other,
         typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Ty2 *, _Ty *>::value,
         void *>::type * = 0)
{   // construct weak_ptr object for resource pointed to by _Other
    this->_Resetw(_Other);
}
```

Q1: Why is the top copy constructor even there? It looks like the bottom one accounts for every case (including the top one). Does it even get called? and if they didn't include it would the bottom one take it's place?

Q2: What's going on with the second argument of the bottom (templated) constructor. I think I understand the SFINAE aspect, but I don't understand why there is an extra * after `::type`

Comment: @Hans, so why not fix the indentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1) If you don't write a copy constructor, the compiler will generate one for you, which wouldn't be what you want. Templated conversion constructors don't count.

Q2) <s>Remember that `shared_ptr<T>` is like a `T*`, convertibility must be checked at the level of pointers. If `T*` is convertible to `U*` then you should be able to assign one to the other. Think of pointers-to-base.</s> [Sorry, that wasn't what you asked.] The final argument type just needs to exist, but also we don't want to have to specify the argument itself. A universal way of making up a type for which we can also provide a default argument is a pointer. In short, we need to make the function depend on a type that may or may not exist, but without actually requiring the user to know about this.

Comment: if that `*` wasn't there before the `=0` it would still be a void* type on success though. Isn't the extra * making it a void**, but why wouldn't they write void** instead of void* in that case?

Also, why didn't they write nullptr instead of 0, is that a mistake?

Comment: @Dave: You don't *have* to use `nullptr`, that's just an optional new feature. Anyway, I'm not sure why you'd need a double pointer in fact, maybe it's just their house style to always use SFINAE via pointers, and they just happened to use `void*` for the inner type in this case. GCC doesn't do this via function arguments at all and instead uses default template arguments to trigger the substitution failure, at zero runtime cost.

Comment: LOL. I just wrote a weak_ptr like thing based on _Ptr_Base and if that second `*` we're talking about isn't there VS says...
`Error 1 error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`
    So, that's why it's there. HA.

Comment: @Dave: Nice. Who knows what compiler idiosyncrasies the library has to tiptoe around... I'm far more worried by the fact that the constructor has a different signature from the documented one!

Answer (score 4):

Re Q1: a templated constructor is never a "copy constructor", even if it manages to copy. if there is no user-defined "copy constructor", then the compiler will generate one as needed.

Re Q2: the second argument, a pointer defaulted to 0, is just to have a place to put the `enable_if`. you can find more about that (if i recall correctly) in the Boost documentation.

Cheers & hth.,